# Who controls the contact picture on iOS in address book?

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts, photos

My son has a inappropriate picture of a girl as her contact photo... When I questioned him about it he said that she had made it her outgoing contact photo and he had no control over it... Is this possible or am I being lied to?!

Comment: There's "could one change it?" and "could _he_ change it?" I've found profile photo syntonization between popular products like Gmail, Facebook, iOS, and OS X to be utter voodoo. So while it may technically be possible to override, he may not know how nor have the time to figure it out.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, it's possible. If you go to the iOS settings app and sign in with either Facebook or Twitter, there is a button to retrieve contact pictures from those services for each contact on your device.

So, your child has the option to change that photo on a case by case basis, but what they said could be entirely true.

At is point, it gets less clear with syncing your address book with Facebook (or other). Presumably it could use each person's Facebook picture, set by them, as their photo in your address book.

I've never seen a picture I assign get overwritten, but it's clearly possible that might happen.

Comment: So if you already have a picture for a contract, the Facebook sync will never overwrite that?

Comment: @KlasMellbourn No, I don't think it will overwrite contact profile pictures that you have already assigned. Contact pictures are an important part of the User Experience, when you're receiving phone calls or texting people, but very few people had profile pictures assigned to their contacts so Apple wanted an easy and quick way to do that.

Answer (score -4):

as Mike Scott says, you can sync and take pics online and set is to your contacts information, however, there is no sutch thing as a "outgoing contact photo"

this means if i have a picture of a pony as MY profile picture, you wont se a pony when i call! unless i have that picture online, like on Facebook, and you synced and downloaded that picture and made it my contact information photo!

*however, this should be added, there could be third party apps, where you decide what pictures others see when they call! like **whatsapp** (only texting), but if it was the native phone app on iOS (was the slide to answer visible?) its not possible!*

**so he can change the pic, if its not a third party "phone" app**